# ASP.Net Webforms not redirecting on successful authentication, but works second try

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webforms, owin

I have an application that accepts local account login requests as well as identity authentication using 3rd party providers, and have an issue that I can't see anyone has had before online.

Essentially, the application hangs when logging in the user. It says `processing request` in the bottom left status bar and hangs indefinitely. Clicking the login button again causes the XSRF token validation to fail (assuming this is the natural expected behaviour). If you don't click the button again, but navigate to an authentication required page, it does recognise the user having successfully authenticated.

If you logout of the application and sign in again (without killing the localhost session), it then authenticates and redirects the user and the app doesn't hang in any other areas either (third party authentication, account management etc). Upon ending the localhost session and rebooting, the application hangs on the first login attempt again.

I have debugged the code and it seems to occur within this section of the `IdentityModels` module:

```vb
    Public Shared Sub RedirectToReturnUrl(returnUrl As String, response As HttpResponse)
        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) AndAlso IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) Then
            response.Redirect(returnUrl)
        Else
            response.Redirect("~/")
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code in my Login function calls this when receiving a `Success` response like so:

```vb
    Select Case loginResult 
        Case SignInStatus.Success
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
            Exit Select
    End Select
```

The code always returns the `Else` response of `response.Redirect("~/")` and this is the line that it hangs on, never redirecting. After logging out the authenticated user and keeping the localhost session alive, the code hits this point again but this time the application redirects successfully on the same line with the same parameters.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Why do you need the `AndAlso IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)` part?  Also use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` instead of just `response.Redirect`. Try to mention the page name for the root reditect `"~/index.aspx"`?

Comment: Thanks, this particular section of code is default Controller code provided by Microsoft. I'll try that, thanks!